# Windsor factory not creating new objects when using LifestyleTransient

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have a situation, where I will be making objects, but I need to get references to other objects, using Windsor. I don't have much experience in this, the title of this post could be even misleading... So I looked around the web, found this [Why would you use Windsor AsFactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062673/why-would-you-use-windsor-asfactory) and decided to try first, using that example. So I created this:

```
public interface INumberWriterFactory
{
    INumberWriter Create(int number);
    INumberWriter Create(int number, IDependencyThatIWillNeed dependency);

}

public interface INumberWriter
{
    void Write();
}

public class NumberWriter : INumberWriter
{
    private int _number;
    private IDependencyThatIWillNeed _dependency;

    public NumberWriter(int number, IDependencyThatIWillNeed dependency)
    {
        _number = number;
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Inside: " + _number);
    }
}
```

I register those with this (`AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>()` is registered somewhere before):

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<INumberWriterFactory>().AsFactory().IsDefault(),
    Component.For<INumberWriter>().ImplementedBy<NumberWriter>().LifestyleTransient().IsDefault());
```

And execute the code like this:

```
var _numberWriterFactory = _container.Resolve<INumberWriterFactory>();

var list = new List<int> { 105042, 162306, 29443 };
foreach (var i in list)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Outside: " + i);
    var numberWriter = _numberWriterFactory.Create(i);
    numberWriter.Write();
}
```

But the output looks like this:

```
Outside: 105042
Inside: 105042
Outside: 162306
Inside: 105042
Outside: 29443
Inside: 105042
```

And I cant understand - Why is it not working? `INumberWriter` is registered as `LifestyleTransient`, so it should create new instance every time, right? Well, it is not. Constructor of `NumberWriter` is reached only once.

Basicly - how do I make new objects, that will have dependencies?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, there must be something else that is not shown that is causing this.  You can (and should) create your own [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to try to determine where the problem is, or you can see [the example I made](https://gist.github.com/pjquirk/fc8d32ff3a60215675e6#file-castle-factory-test-cs), and go from there.

Comment: The fact, that it worked for you, and not for me, helped me to narrow down mistakes! Now I found, that container at one point uses this `container.Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder.AddContributor(new SingletonEqualizer());` If I move my `.Register` before that, it works.