# Castle Winsdor - Propagating dependency passed via typed factory

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am currently getting familiar with IoC and having difficulties regarding refactoring of an existing library using IoC principles.

Let's say I have three classes: **Controller**, **Handler** and **Settings** and a typed factory for Controller.

- **Controller** is an entry point of the library

  ```
  public class Controller
  {
      public Settings Settings { get; }
      public Handler  Handler  { get; }

      public Controller(Settings settings, Handler handler)
      {
          Settings = settings;
          Handler  = handler;
      }
  }
  ```
- **Handler** is a dependency of Controller

  ```
  public class Handler
  {
      public Settings Settings { get; }

      public Handler(Settings settings)
      {
          Settings = settings;
      }
  }
  ```
- **Settings** is a class containing some library-wide settings'

  ```
  public class Settings
  {
      public int Revision { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- **IControllerFactory** is a typed factory

  ```
  public interface IControllerFactory
  {
      Controller Create(Settings settings);
  }
  ```

---

I want to initialize a library. For sake of simplicity, all example code is in a single Main method. In real world application, consumer of Controller class does not have access to container.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //create container and register components
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
    container.Register(
        Component.For<Controller>().LifestyleTransient(),
        Component.For<Settings>().LifestyleBoundTo<Controller>(),
        Component.For<Handler>().LifestyleBoundTo<Controller>()
    );
    container.Register(
        Component.For<IControllerFactory>().AsFactory()
    );

    //in real application, factory is a dependency of a library consumer class 
    //which has no access to container
    var controllerFactory = container.Resolve<IControllerFactory>();

    //create Controller instance with Revision setting set to 100
    var settings = new Settings()
    {
        Revision = 100
    };
    var controller = controllerFactory.Create(settings);

    //check revision value for controller and handler
    Console.WriteLine("Controller's setting revision: " + controller.Settings.Revision);         //Controller's setting revision: 100
    Console.WriteLine("Handler's setting revision: "    + controller.Handler.Settings.Revision); //Handler's setting revision: 0
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Running this example outputs the following:

```
Controller's setting revision: 100
Handler's setting revision: 0
```

As you can see, Settings instance which is passed as an argument to a factory is correctly passed to Controller constructor but **does not propagate to Controller's dependencies** (i.e. Handler constructor). I couldn't find any information on whether it is an intended behaviour.

---

If arguments of typed factories are actually non-propagatable, **what approach would you suggest in my situation**? Creating custom scope is one, but doesn't suite my needs because it requires access to the container, which as far as I understand is considered a bad practice.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //create container and register components
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
    container.Register(
        Component.For<Controller>().LifestyleScoped(),
        Component.For<Settings>().LifestyleScoped(),
        Component.For<Handler>().LifestyleBoundTo<Controller>()
    );

    //creating scope means passing container around
    using (container.BeginScope()) 
    {
        //create instance of controller
        var settings = container.Resolve<Settings>();
        settings.Revision = 100;
        var controller = container.Resolve<Controller>();

        //check revision value for controller and handler
        Console.WriteLine("Controller's setting revision: " + controller.Settings.Revision);         //Controller's setting revision: 100
        Console.WriteLine("Handler's setting revision: "    + controller.Handler.Settings.Revision); //Handler's setting revision: 100
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Running this example gives a desired result:

```
Controller's setting revision: 100
Handler's setting revision: 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments passed to a factory will not be added to the container - they will only be used to satisfy dependencies of the required service. If you wish those arguments to be passed down to other dependencies you must take responsibility for doing this yourself.

The general rule-of-thumb that referencing the container is bad practice is correct. However, like all rules-of-thumb it has limits.

(The actual variability of `Settings` is not clear from your question so I am assuming your implied requirement, that it can vary in an unspecified way, is the key driver here. However, answering your question about *"what approach would you suggest"* is difficult without properly understanding the real variability of `Settings`)

i) With your current design, one way or another you need to augment the behavior of the container to fulfill your requirements as explained and you must, therefore, access the container.

As you have already highlighted, one solution would be to use custom scopes. This provides great flexibility in controlling object life cycle but does leak the container reference in a fairly dangerous way. To avoid this, you can encapsulate this to prevent leakage of the container, and you will end up with a custom factory and a partner scope class (which may simply be an `IDisposable` as far as clients are concerned). In this scenario, I regard this as an augmentation of the container's baseline functionality and therefore the rule-of-thumb does not apply.

ii) Another approach would be to rethink your design a little and introduce some indirection to the referencing of `Settings`. i.e. instead of `Handler` and `Controller` having a dependency on `Settings`, they could have a dependency on `SettingsProvider`. `SettingsProvider` could then be added to the container as a singleton and the required logic about how to access the currently applicable `Settings` could be managed completely independently of the container.

(See this [excellent explanation of the benefits of factories in Castle Windsor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25066327/246811) for further details)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, I don't think I follow your question regarding the `Settings` variable but will still try to clarify this point. 
Basically, `Settings` properties must be set up by a `Controller` consumer and the resulting `Settings` instance must be passed to the specific `Controller` and all its dependencies. After that, none of  `Settings` properties are changed and are not accessed from anywhere else but the corresponding `Controller`.
I actually didn't know it is possible to create a concrete factory with your own implementation, so I'll use this approach.